# formula to convert parentid to parent name

Tags: formula-field

In custom object I had used hyperlink formula for related to field,i want parent id record name in hyperlink that should redirect to Parentid(where parentid consist of either accountid,leadid,oppid) record page. but getting object record name

```
HYPERLINK("url",parentid,"_blank")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:-

```
HYPERLINK("/" &  AccountId , "" &  Account.Name , "_blank")
```

Here, we have one custom formula field Contact and it will show  the hyperlink with text Account Name associated with that Contact.

Comment: But the author has different parent objects, how to decide which to use?

Comment: It's not working....having different parent objects

Comment: HYPERLINK("url/"&ParentID__c, Name  ,"_blank ") in place of Name(object name) i want ParentID__c name